# If Entities, in the Clean Architecture, are enterprise wide rules how different applications consume them?

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, enterprise-architecture, clean-architecture

In this [post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), Uncle Bob writes:

> Entities encapsulate Enterprise wide business rules. An entity can be an object with methods, or it can be a set of data structures and functions. It doesn’t matter so long as the entities could be used by many different applications in the enterprise.

If I understood correctly, entities are business rules that apply to the whole company. It's what defines the business. And the rules that the entities embody can be executed by one or many applications that make the whole enterprise system.

I'm thinking in terms of a company that has dozens of microservices and multiple web-apps, all in different programming languages. How is it possible to centralize enterprise wide business rules in such scenario?

Comment: "the rules that the entities embody can be executed by one or many applications" - primarily in principle, though, with effort, sometimes and to some extent in practice. It's not so much what defines the business, but what, in business terms, defines central aspects of the particular problem the application tackles. The thing is, while these entities capture these rules explicitly in code, the entities themselves aren't necessarily fully functional elements - they require things to use them, or things to be plugged into the application core, for something to actually happen.

Comment: With microservices, you have small, very focused services, a number of which roughly form such a core - think of the same overall idea, but on a level of interacting microservices, instead of interacting classes/objects, taking into consideration the added constraints, like communication over the network, etc.

Answer (score 2):

## In short

This definition of entities is confusing due to the misleading use of  “***rules***”.  Entities are long lived objects, and R.C. Martin's point is that they use to be shared between several applications.

The entities being known via their interface, different micro-services may use the same interface definitions, for example with the help of an [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language), but implement them differently.

## Some more arguments

### What entities are really about

In the seminal [Clean Architecture post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) that you quote, R.C.Martin builds on existing architectural models that he merged. Basically, the [hexagonal architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) and the onion architecture focus on inversion of control and the outer cores. They are are not very prescriptive about the inner core.

R.C.Martin therefore borrowed use-cases and entities from the [Boundary-Contral-Entity pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) to subdivide further the inner core. BCE defines entities as classes that are of meaning for the business.  Unfortunately, it used a very data-oriented terminology. Martin used "business rule" to insist on the behavioral aspects that mey be shared across the applications.

But R.C. Martin clarified what he meant with a refined definition in his *Clean Architecture* book:

> An Entity is an object within our computer system that embodies a small set of critical business rules operating on Critical Business Data. The Entity object either contains the Critical Business Data or has very easy access to that data. The interface of the Entity consists of the functions that implement the Critical Business Rules that operate on that data.

Now, if we read it many time, we start to understand that it's in fact that "Critical Business Data" means "information relevant for the business" and the "Rules" are nothing more than the behavioral features that operate on the data.

In case of doubt, you can read the example illustrating the entity definition in his book:  it's a simple example of a Loan, with 3 properties (`principle`, `rate`, `period`) and 3 methods (`makePayment()`, `applyInterest()`, `chargeLateFee()`).

### Why is it confusing?

The use of "business rule" to describe a method of an entity is confusing.  In his example, `makePayment()` and `applyInterest()` are just fact of life for a loan.  It's more "business logic" (i.e. domain model logic) than "business rule".

Moreover, there's an additional ambiguity here, because any reasonable business analyst would use the term "business rule", to define some general rules that are true independently of the use-case and the entity, and often "business"-specific (where business may refer to a company). Of course, some of these business rules can be embodied in an operation of the class. But often business rules involve more than one entity.

The *Clean Architecture* book is full of good ideas, but nevertheless judged by many as [confusing](https://dev.to/bosepchuk/why-i-cant-recommend-clean-architecture-by-robert-c-martin-ofd). I share this opinion, because it does not help to improve communication, when an alternate terminology is introduced.  In the same way, the use of "use-case" to describe a business function/transaction is equally misleading.  Personally, I would not have grasped the article without going back to the onion architecture and BCE, or reading the additional explanations/examples in the book.

### Entities consumed by different applications

Sharing entities between different microservices and different implementation language is another story. The key here is that the entities are defined by their interface.

One strategy is to assigne the responsibility for an entity to a well defined microservice that will manage it and enforce any business rules. But this will not address the issues related to elementary up-stream consistency of the data sent to those services. Nor does it address the use of the object down-stream.

You’ll find many questions on SE about this narrowed down topic (search with tag `microservice` and keyword `shared`), so I will not develop it further here.

Comment: Interesting to see a different perspective than my own. I do agree that Martin tends not to be too careful with his phrasing (so a lot of what he says comes of as hard rules, even though they aren't, when you dig deeper and/or look at some of his other work). And the industry as a whole has an unfortunate tendency of reinventing the wheel, and to reuse same names for different things. I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation of what he means by "entities",  though. I'm fairly certain that for both Martin and Ivar Jacobson (from whose work BCE derives), ... 1/2

Comment: ... an entity is *not* about persistence; both of them put emphasis on behavior. It's not about data that survives the application; Jacobson's use of "long-lived" was more in the sense of "hangs out in RAM". E.g., for Martin, it's either a proper object or {data structure + functions}. I think he quite literally means that these objects capture certain rules. A rule does not refer to a method, it's more "if the entity is in this state, this method will do this thing", or "these objects will be considered equal only under these conditions", or "changing this will affect this, but not this". 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović thank you for your comment. I think that the important point in my argument is that entities are not “business rules” but are objects that matter to the users (i.e. domain/business objects, and not some technical object the users do not even know about). The peristance is not from me, and anyway is an ambiguous term. It is used by Jacobson, Booch and Rumbaugh in USDP (page 346 “long lived and often persistent”) and I reused the definition as-is

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I also agree with you that USDP definition by the UML founders is not perfect either, because an Entity more than information. To their excuse, when they worked on the topic, the term Entity was yet dominantly used for ER modelling which was indeed data oriented, and they had to explain their views to a majority that was not used to OOD.  But it would have been wiser for RC Martin to improve the original definition instead of starting from the scratch and promoting confusion.

Comment: I don't think of business rules as of abstract technical objects. E.g. business users / domain experts very much care about a rule like "a shipment can be canceled without paying a fee if cancellation is requested at least 5 business days prior to scheduled departure" (I'm making the example up). You have to put that into the system somehow; you might as well explicitly encapsulate the rule in some object (say, `ShipmentCancellation` or something). Or if you prefer functions + pure data, there will be functions + inputs capturing the rule. Note that it is not tied to a particular use case.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović of course the kind of business rule that you describe makes perfect sense. Let me clarify my thoughts: “a shipment can be cancelled at least (…)” does not describe an entity. The entity will probably be “Shipment” or perhaps “Cancelation request”.   The business rule could indeed be encapsulated in such entity.  But very often business rules are about more than one entity (here in fact it’s about cancellation request ans shipment; maybe some contract allow exception to that rule). This is why I find Uncle Bob’s definition very misleading.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Let me also disambiguate my comment: an object that would certainly not be an entity is `OKButton` or `CancellationListener` or even `DialogWindow`. These are all important classes, but they are not relevant for the users and the business stakeholders. (And I could develop a solution addressing the user needs using very different classes.) Would you agree about this understanding of what an entity is or is not?

Comment: Yes, yes, that's pretty much spot on, in its essence; I think any leftover disagreement or confusion is due to terminology. You're right, some rules/behaviors span multiple entities, and should be explicitly captured into their own object, rather than, say, spread throughout the multiple entities (SRP, cohesion). I think Uncle Bob would categorize such objects as entities as well; in any case, they would fall into the same architectural layer, and may or may not have a database representation. 1/2

Comment: I think DDD, for example, expresses a similar idea; in fact I think the idea of an aggregate root (as originally defined by Evans) is a version of that (the root acting as a facade enforcing behavioral constraints across the aggregate). Jacobson gives similar motivation for his Control objects (a single place to put behavior that would otherwise be spread out). But you're right that the term "entity" is unfortunately chosen. E.g., I know it's terribly confusing for the C# crowd, due to prevalence of Entity Framework, where an entity is essentially a database row. 2/2

Comment: * "I think Uncle Bob would categorize such objects as entities as well" - that is, if the kind of rules they capture are core business rules like the ones we've discussed (I don't think he bans entities to be a part of some object structure). His layers are based on a high-level division of responsibilities, I think; structurally, the same sort of an "orchestrator" object could appear in the "use-cases" layer, if it encapsulates rules that are more application-specific.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Interesting. Thanks for the fruitful and constructive exchange. I think we share similar backgrounds and there is no substantial divergence. Ambiguous terminology is a fact of life and I appreciate that we could look under the terminological surface :-)

Answer (score 0):

My response is a bit of an oversimplification, and many microservices approaches don't align with it; but I contend those approaches precisely hit a weakness by not recognizing those central point needs.

Any organization needs a "source of truth" for some critical data, that is widely consumed. For example, a company that is centered around their customers and bills them, will have a central, well defined approach to identify what is a customer, what is an invoice, how they manage taxes.

Even if you have different microservices handling those, for example separate microservices handling US, Canada and Mexico customers, using different approaches for data like addresses, zipcodes and tax rates, which follow different rules; you will want to have some abstraction to handle them together, so you don't need to reinvent how you match your product catalog to each of them; or how you send emails to your customers. So you want an enterprise architecture that handles the higher level common concept, even if the implementation details are different. A follow up example: Budget may consume data from all of those, and convert to a single currency before reporting to HQ.

Then, in order to operate and integrate the data, you will need some very general concepts that define how the aggregate operates; for example, in a multinational company with many subsidiaries following distinct laws and incorporated separately on each country, you want to have a common country catalog, that very particularly represents the knowledge of what countries you can do business with. You don't want the website in Japan to show different data on the subsidiaries around the world, than what the mobile app in Brazil shows.

So, once we have clarified the need of those central rules, with these not-detailed examples. You may still choose (actively or by lack of action) to ignore those central rules, but you will live the consequences through system integration issues.

Then, to implement the "central" rules, you have many approaches. Just a few (that you can combine for different problems):

a) Data-centric approach + replication: You decide where the source of truth resides (generally HQ), that is the read/write copy for the data representing the central rules; and that central storage is regularly queried (for example, a global web service) by the subsidiaries, which may cache it; or strictly replicated on a schedule (like every night), creating as many copies as performance requires

b) Local data + backup at HQ: Each country / division / shard owns the data for their subset; when a non-local system requires the data, they always get it from the local source (which may be a "remote" web service from their perspective). The only commonality is the standard protocol and fields that work the same for all separate subsystem

c) Service centric approach : Every system interrogates an apparently common service about the rules. But local areas can adjust service routes so you may have alternative implementations for the common service.

On any case, all the system is exposed whenever you make breaking changes to those central rules; but missing those central rules exposes the subsystems to incompatibilities and friction on integration.